# Are the confidence intervals and p-value for this risk consistent?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, p-value, relative-risk

I'm trying to calculate a risk ratio with the following 2x2 contingency table, where the rows are exposure groups and the columns are disease status. The first row of the matrix shows that 1/38 exposed participants developed the disease.

```
              Disease +   Disease -   Total  
 ----------- ----------- ----------- ------- 
  Exposed             1          37      38  
  Unexposed          26         120     146
```

(Example code using R)

```
library(epitools)
study_results <- matrix(c(120, 37, 26, 1), ncol = 2)
epitools::riskratio(study_results)
```

This gives a risk ratio of 0.15 (95% CI 0.02-1.05).

The p-value (null hypothesis is risk ratio = 1) is about 0.01, depending on the method. Why is the p-value clearly lower than 0.05, when the 95% confidence interval crosses 1?

Comment: As a general rule, when asking questions about specific data with specific procedures in statistical software, it is best to cut and paste the **exact input and output,** rather than your transcription, paraphrase, or interpretation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the exact type of test
used by the procedure `riskratio`. It may be
that you have too little data to get an accurate
result from that procedure. Also I have found that
various tests for count data in R
require different formats for data
input; please check the documentation.

Here are results from Fisher's exact test in R.
Fisher's test gives accurate results for $2 \times 2$
contingency tables with low counts.

```
fisher.test(study_results <- matrix(c(120, 37, 26, 1), ncol = 2))

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  study_results <- matrix(c(120, 37, 26, 1), ncol = 2)
p-value = 0.01869
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.002967902 0.819951147
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
 0.1255829
```

By contrast, Pearson's chi-squared test, which
does not always work well with small counts, gives
a somewhat different P-value (and says nothing directly
about odds ratios).

[1] 70

> fisher.test(study_results <- matrix(c(120, 37, 26, 1), ncol = 2))

Comment: Thanks, @BruceET